# Newman's Lemma or Diamond Lemma

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics

I'd like to learn the Newman's Lemma or Diamond Lemma (the one used in abstract rewriting system), can someone recommend me some books where I can read it? I'd appreciate self-contained books with examples. Thank you.

Comment: See also Chapter 1 in my book "Combinatorial Algebra: syntax and semantics" https://www.amazon.com/Combinatorial-Algebra-Semantics-Monographs-Mathematics/dp/331908030X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1514304724&sr=8-1&keywords=Combinatorial+algebra%3A+syntax+and+semantics.

Comment: @Mark Sapir : Thank you very much for the reference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- [Franz Baader and Tobias Nipkow, *Term Rewriting and All That*](https://www21.in.tum.de/~nipkow/TRaAT/) is a book fully devoted to term rewriting; much of it is about applying the diamond lemma.
- [Vincent van Oostrom, *Newman's proof of Newman's lemma*](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=98C760060ED7C8CBA02612BDC53EF201) proves the lemma itself on just 1 page. That's not the shortest proof.
- [Gert Smolka, *Confluence and Normalization in Reduction Systems*](https://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/courses/sem-ws15/ars.pdf) proves the diamond lemma in §15, after showing all sorts of related things. These notes are clearly written for computer scientists (the notations resemble Coq), but from what I've seen are fairly readable.
- [Kimmo Eriksson, *Strong convergence and the polygon property of 1-player games*, Discrete Mathematics, Volume 153, Issues 1--3, 1 June 1996, Pages 105--122](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(95)00131-F) explores the "Polygon property theorem", which is similar to the diamond lemma. (It requires the play sequences to be of the same length, which makes it somewhat more restrictive, but its conclusion is accordingly stronger.)
- [George M. Bergman, *The diamond lemma for ring theory*, Advances in Mathematics, Volume 29, Issue 2, February 1978, Pages 178--218](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(78)90010-5) ([errata](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/papers/updates/diamond.html)) applies the diamond lemma to the study of algebras.
- As @MarkSapir pointed out, [Mark Sapir, *Combinatorial algebra: syntax and
  semantics*, Springer 2014](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/sapirmv/book/b2.pdf) has a section (§1.7) on confluence.
- [Marc Bezem, Thierry Coquand, *Newman's Lemma -- a Case Study in Proof Automation and Geometric Logic*](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~coquand/bul.ps) proves a "bi-colored" analogue of Newman's lemma.
- [Lars Hellström, *The Diamond Lemma for Power Series Algebras*](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/record.jsf?pid=diva2%3A145049&dswid=-6405) gives an analogue of the ring-theoretical diamond lemma for infinite-but-sort-of-convergent rewriting sequences (I am being deliberately vague here, since I've read only the motivating sections of this).

Self-containedness isn't really an issue in this subject; the proof of the lemma is usually less than a page long, and there are zero prerequisites. I once gave an [expository talk about confluence](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/diamond-talk.pdf) that includes a proof of the diamond lemma.

Comment: I don’t know if it is a good place to learn about it, but a classical reference, in terms of establishing terminology and the proof techniques, is Gérard Huet, "Confluent Reductions: Abstract Properties and Applications to Term Rewriting Systems"

Comment: Btw, I’m not 100% convinced about the self-contained was of the proof because the proof I know uses Noetherian induction, and the proof that Noetherian induction works is probably a subtle argument from logic or set-theory or something

Comment: Oh, okay. I meant "self-contained up to the foundational questions", which are different from use to use anyway. The easiest case (apart from that when the system has only finitely many states) is when you assume an induction predicate over the term-rewriting relation; this is what Bezem and Coquand do, if I remember correctly. (See Definition 3.2 in their paper.) This might be annoyingly abstract to some, but it completely sidesteps constructivity issues, as far as I understand.

Comment: @darijgrinberg:  The transfinite induction is not needed. See the proof of 1.7.2 of my book.

Comment: @MarkSapir: Your proof of Theorem 1.7.10 (with its use of the termination condition) is not constructive either. The induction predicate in Bezem-Coquand is not really transfinite; for example, in the most commonly used case (when each rewriting step decreases some finite tuple with respect to lexicographic order), it boils down to a double (or triple? I forgot) induction. The resulting algorithm can be incredibly slow (Ackermann or worse), because it's not primitive recursive, but this is still allowed in constructivism.

Comment: @darijgrinberg:  The proof cannot be constructive for obvious reasons. In the book, a rewriting system is an arbitrary directed graph. The diamond lemma is used throughout the book not only for term rewriting but  also for "automata rewriting" and "diagram rewriting", for example.

Comment: @MarkSapir: In your form, the lemma cannot be proven constructively. In the Bezem-Coquand form, it can. All it takes is the induction predicate, which can be constructively proven in all cases I've ever used the lemma in. I have not read your whole book, but I suspect that the majority of your situations fits the bill: The thing being rewritten doesn't itself have to decrease lexicographically; only some semi-invariant has to.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: The proof cannot be constructive because the class of rewriting systems is not a set. Less obviously, I am not sure whether Buchberger algorithm over uncountable field is "constructive" enough. It is not "my" form of the lemma, it is Newman's original formulation. In my part of mathematics nobody is interested in constructive proofs of Newman's lemma. But we are interested in constructive description of terminal elements of rewriting systems (canonical forms) which in most applications can be done.

Comment: @MarkSapir: Sets vs. classes isn't a particularly useful distinction in constructive type theory; nor does countability significantly matter. Yes, I guess Newman's original statement is non-constructive or constructively useless (anything that requires infinite chains to stabilize is constructively useless -- instead, the "right" way to state Noetherianness is by requiring Noetherian induction to hold, which is exactly what Bezem & Coquand do with their predicate). What I mean is the following. Since I've never seen the really deep applications, let me ...

Comment: ... do a simple example. If you have a finite family of monic polynomials generating an ideal, and you know that the S-polynomial of every two of them reduces to $0$ with respect to this family, then this family is a Gröbner basis (i.e., each polynomial uniquely reduces to a reduced form by the standard "division algorithm" rewriting system using this family). You can prove this constructively using the diamond lemma, both for the deg-lex order (which is easy enough) and for the lex order (using an inductive predicate a la Bezem & Coquand, which in term is proven by double induction). ...

Comment: ... Probably some more complicated situations (when inductive predicates are over trees or graphs?) require infinitary methods, but I haven't seen them used much in my kind of algebra (where things tend to be graded most of the time and lexicographic otherwise).

Comment: One thing that is indeed an issue with non-discrete rings (or classes) is that we might "never know that we're done", i.e., if we cannot tell whether a coefficient is $0$, we might keep reducing it forever without changing it. My impression is that the Noetherian-induction reasoning still works with appropriate modifications. I'm not sure about it.

Comment: @MarkSapir: thanks for pointing out the proof in your textbook. I had thought that transfinite induction was required in some essential way.